# How would I go about doing a conditional format on a range for each current cell with vlookup?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to create a conditional format across an entire range that would check on the product's availability status. So far I could get it to work using

`=(vlookup(A3, F2:G15, 2, False) = "Out of Stock")`

But it's only working for the referenced cell, which in this case is A3. Is there a way to set it up so the conditional format checks the cell it is formatting?

**Docs:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L3NSxalwBHYOsqfZfspLfxUlixyPMq9h2SyZ6GdZLpo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in a different forum, which worked for me. Hope it helps anyone who encounters the same use case!

> this works for in stock
>
> ```
> =match(A16,Filter($F$3:$F,$G$3:$G="In Stock") ,0)
> ```
>
> others are simple variations & different color